# Using Regex to Split String

Tags: regex, extendscript, adobe-bridge

So I have a string like this (the hashtags are delimiters)

```
A1###B2###C3###12345.jpg
```

I was wondering how would I access A1, B2 and C3

```
STRING1###STRING2###STRING3###STRING4.jpg
SOME###THING###HERE###MEH.jpg
EXTRACT###THIS###PLEASE###pah.jpg
```

In one instance I'd like to extract the first string. In another the second, in another the third. I will be using this with Adobe Bridge to extract metadata items from the filename

I am looping through each filename so would need

```
Var1 = FirstString
Var2 = SecondString
Var3 = ThirdString
```

Comment: Anything? Really? Could they be `B2` or `C3`? Are they fixed length? What language are you using?

Comment: Who's downvoting the answers? They answer the question as written.

Comment: https://i.chzbgr.com/completestore/12/8/21/uEYRq9DvQUOanGpesRk_eQ2.png

Comment: Within reason. I basically have 3 strings that can be delimited by hashtags

Comment: So, `#` means the delimiter used?

Comment: You need to give several real examples of the particular strings you want, and what you want extracted from them.  Your generalized examples are completely unclear.

Comment: That’s much better. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[^#]+(?=###)
```

will match all substrings in your strings that are followed by `###`

```
>>> s = "STRING1###STRING2###STRING3###STRING4.jpg"
>>> import re
>>> re.findall("[^#]+(?=###)", s)
['STRING1', 'STRING2', 'STRING3']
```

Or, for the example in your comment:

```
>>> s = "Slayer###Reading Festival###James###123.jpg"
>>> artist, event, photographer = re.findall("[^#]+(?=###)", s)
>>> artist
'Slayer'
>>> event
'Reading Festival'
>>> photographer
'James'
```

Assuming that Adobe Bridge has an ECMAScript-based scripting engine, you can use a different regex:

```
var myregexp = /^([^#]+)###([^#]+)###([^#]+)###/;
var match = myregexp.exec(subject);
if (match != null) {
    artist = match[1];
    event = match[2];
    photographer = match[3];
}
```

Comment: So let's say I have Slayer###Reading Festival###James###123.jpg. How would I assign Slayer to the variable artist, Reading Festival to event and James to Photographer?

Comment: @JanuszJasinski: See my edit. (The language used is Python; you didn't specify which language you would be using, so I picked the one  I know best.)

Comment: I am using it within Adobe Bridge JavaScript (JSX)

Comment: @JanuszJasinski: OK, I've added an ECMAScript-based answer. I would expect that to work in JSX, too.

Answer (score -1):

This would be your regular expression:

```
(A1).*(B2).*(C3).*\.jpg
```

This will capture the three parts you want, while ignoring the rest of the string.

To access the parts, you just use \1,\2\,\3 respectively.

Comment: I should be more clear

STRING1###STRING2###STRING3###STRING4.jpg

In one instance I'd like to extract the first string. In another the second, in another the third. I will be using this with Adobe Bridge to extract metadata items from the filename

Comment: No, this is wrong.  You can only use things like `\1`, `\2`, and `\3` within the very same pattern, not outside of it, and even then only in certain flavors of pattern-matching languages.